# nginx. Сервер возвращает только json объект

Tags: reactjs, node.js, nginx

У меня такая проблема.
Есть два скрипта 1-й react 2-й nodejs express.
Они практически ничего не делают, react скрипт при первой загрузке обращается к маршруту "/" и получает в ответ json файл, который размещает у себя в разметке.
Запрос из react:

```
function App() {

  const [data, setData] = useState(null);

  useEffect(() => {
    const fetchData = async () => {
      try {
       console.log('Making request to server...');
      const response = await axios.get('https://m.calc5.ru'); // запрос 
      console.log('Response received from server:', response);
      setData(response.data.message);
      } catch (error) {
        console.error('Ошибка при выполнении запроса:', error);
      }
    };

    fetchData();
  }, []);


return (
    <div className="App">
    <header className="App-header">
      <h1>Данные с сервера</h1>
      <div>
      {data ? (
        <div>Данные загружены: {data}</div>
      ) : (
        <div>Загрузка данных...</div>
      )}
      </div>
    </header>
  </div>
  );
}
```

ответ nodejs:

```
app.get('/', (req, res)=>{
    console.log(`зашел в маршрут /`);
     res.json({ message: 'Node running' });
})
```

Если я делаю запрос с локальной машины запустив react скрипт, т.е. запускаю localhost:3000, при этом запрос остается на https://m.calc5.ru, то данные отображаются нормально, я вижу в браузере:
**Данные с сервера
Данные загружены: Node running**
Я сделал деплой скрипта на firebase по адресу https://calc5test.web.app/ и так же получаю корректные данные.
Но если я запускаю react скрипт на vds сервере, т.е. и клиентский и серверный скрипт работают на одной машине, и перехожу по адресу https://m.calc5.ru/ то я получаю в ответ только json:
{
"message": "Node running"
}
И html разметка затирается. Видимо я не до конца понимаю правила взаимодействия клиентского и серверного скрипта на одной машине когда к ним добавляется nginx.
В чем может быть причина такого поведения?

Comment: А какого поведения вы ожидали, если на `/` работает сервер и отвечает джсоном?